# What's the best way to set local JS variables from JSON

Tags: javascript

I'd like to do something like the following w/o using eval(). What's the best way to do that?

```
config: function(config) {
  for (var key in config) {
    if (config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log('setting: ' + key + ' = ' + config[key]);
      eval(key + ' = "' + config[key] + '"');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have JSON. You have a normal JavaScript object. You can make the keys to global variables by setting them as properties of the `window` object (all global variables are properties of the `window` object and using `eval` makes them global):

```
window[key] = config[key];
```

But note that this might overwrite already set values or even nativ `window` properties. To avoid this, you might want to test whether the property already exists first:

```
if(!(key in window)) {
    window[key] = config[key];
}
```

As global variables are bad, it might be better to assign the properties only to the object where the `config` function is defined on. This would be `this[key] = config[key]` if you call the function with `obj.config(someConfiguration)`.

In any way you have to assign them to some object. You cannot make them local to a function otherwise. In the end it depends on *where* you want to have access to the configuration values.